# What are some good calculus resources relevant for Machine learning researcher aspirant?

Tags: machine-learning, references, calculus

I am trying to self-taught myself on Calculus for machine learning and read the [book](https://archive.org/details/spivak-m.-calculus-2008/mode/1up) by Spivak. But it is too rigorous and need a lot of time to finish it.

As far as I am concerned, Calculus is only used for optimization in machine learning.

I am seeking some good calculus resources especially apt for machine learning research but less rigorous than Spivak.

Edited: After some research, I plan on going through MIT OpenCourseWare on single, multivariable calculus and differential equations. What book should I read to study calculus along watching these lectures?

Comment: Close-voters: we have a [tag:references] tag, and questions on references are specifically on-topic. I will add the tag and vote to keep this question open.

Comment: I think this is off-topic because calculus is a fundamental tool. I wager no one has "specialized" calculus for machine learning. But if you search "calculus reference" on math.stackexchange.com, you get literally hundreds of useful posts https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=calculus+reference

Comment: A "hack" text for this would be the Schaum's outline series. These can be bought used for pennies at used book stores or online. It's nothing but definitions and worked problems, the ultimate slacker's guide. They are also available for differential equations and linear algebra assuming you're looking for the pressure cooker solution to my outline here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609570/what-is-the-roadmap-to-self-taught-probability-and-statistics-for-artificial-int

Comment: @StephanKolassa, while references are certainly on-topic, asking for the "best" source, I deem, is opinion-based.

Comment: @User1865345: seriously? Especially in a community full of non-native speakers, this feels like unnecessary nitpicking to me. If OP asked for just *any* reference, that would be OK?

Comment: @User1865345 you could WLOG edit the question, presumably the votes will help determine the best, to ask for any reference and vote to reopen, although I would still say to close it.

Comment: Hm. I agree @StephanKolassa with this. Rewording can change a lot. So I would vote to reopen once it is reframed to a reference post.

Comment: @AdamO, this should  come from the author. I can edit one thing or other but a substantial change should come from the original poster.

Comment: @User1865345 I disagree, this might be a question for meta. My understanding is that if a new user has a closed question and there's an obvious edit that doesn't ruin the spirit of the ask but makes the question on-topic - on this point I agree with Stephan - you should edit the question to an acceptable format.

Comment: Very well @AdamO.

Comment: To the original poster, I have edited the way I feel the question should be. Feel free to change accordingly if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a book and not addressing optimization, but one of the best resources to self-learn calculus are the [lectures by Gilbert Strang](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBE9407EA64E2C318) that were recorded and are available on YouTube. He also wrote a great handbook.

If you would find Strang a little bit too hard, I'll recommend starting with the [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) lectures.

Comment: Strang is a national treasure.

Comment: I followed his linear algebra classes religiously; the calculus would also be definitely worth it.